# C++ perform if-not-equal-then-increment atomically using acquire-release semantics?

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, atomic, stdatomic

Below I have some of a lock implementation.

The lock is available if `m_counter != -1`. If this condition is true, increment `m_counter`.

Is it possible to implement the `!=` and `++` atomically/CAS and using acquire-release semantics (rather than sequentially consistent) for performance and correctness?  (If another thread changes `m_counter` to `-1` after we've passed the `!= -1` check, this thread could increment from `-1` to `0`.)

```
#include <atomic>

struct Lock
{
    void take_lock()
    {
        while(true)
        {

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//          Perform this commented-section atomically and using acquire-release semantics?

            if(-1 != m_counter)
            {
                // race condition here if compare+increment isn't one atomic op
                ++m_counter;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                return;
            }

            while(-1 == m_counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
            {

            }
        }
    }

    std::atomic<int8_t> m_counter{0};
};
```

Comment: Yes in C++, no in x86 assembly for weaker than SC.  You'll need a CAS retry loop.  Unless you can wait a couple years for a CPU with the CMPccXADD extension, (according to Intel's [future-extensions](https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/782879/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf) asm manual, planned for Sierra Forest, Grand Ridge, Arrow Lake, Lunar Lake.)  In that case, `CMPNZXADD m32, r32, r32` can atomically compare-and-maybe-add if `m32 != second_operand`.  You'd have to use a 32-bit counter, though; the instruction's only available with 32 or 64-bit operand-size.

Comment: If you're doing a readers/writers lock or something, can you use the high bit as your lock-taken state?  So you can always increment (`m_counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)`) and you find out if the value was negative (high bit set in the fetch_add return value)?  x86 can efficiently do that with `lock xadd`, and efficiently set the high bit with `lock or` or `lock bts`.  (If your counter can come close to overflowing into the high bit, that's a problem.)

Comment: Hopefully you wouldn't need to `fetch_sub` to undo an add if you find the high bit was set; that might be worse than a CAS retry loop, especially in lowish contention situations where CAS usually succeeds on the first try.

Comment: Also note, that in the while loop you can use a cpu instruction to specifically say, that you are waiting in a spinlock, which allows the cpu to remove some speculative members in the pipeline and save power.
On x86_64 it is the pause instruction, major compilers have a built-in function.

Comment: How do you set the `m_counter` to `-1`? I guess you're trying to implement a semaphore. Don't bother if that's the case: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore

Comment: Note that your original code has a race condition: After `if (-1 != m_counter)`, another thread might change the counter to `-1`, and then your `++m_counter` will increment from `-1` which is what you wanted to avoid.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I think the code in the question is pseudo-code; the comment *Perform this commented-section atomically...* seems to be a problem statement / wishlist, not a description of what the current code actually does.  Oh wait, the text does say "for performance"; I had assumed they realized it was necessary for correctness.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. I agree that it was unclear whether the comment was "describing what the code does" or "Describing what I wish the code could do". I read it as "describing what the code does", but perhaps the other meaning was intended.

Answer (score 1):

not quit clear what you try implement, but i assume that next code can be a solution

```
#include <limits>
#include <atomic>

struct Lock
{
    std::atomic_int m_counter { INT_MIN };

    [[nodiscard]] bool take_lock()
    {
        int counter = m_counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        
        while ( 0 > counter )
        {       
            // insert delay here (Sleep or MessageBox for simulate raice)
            if (m_counter.compare_exchange_weak(counter, counter + 1, std::memory_order_acquire))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    void OnRundown()
    {
        // DestroyResource();
    }

    void free_lock()
    {
        if (1 == m_counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release))
        {
            OnRundown();
        }
    }

    void BeginRunDown()
    {
        if (take_lock())
        {
            m_counter.fetch_add(INT_MIN, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            free_lock();
        }
    }
};
```

this can be used for protect some resource and safe destroy it, after all usage end

threads can use this like

```
void some_func(Lock* lock)
{
    if (lock->take_lock())
    {
        // we can safe use resourse
        // resourse will be not destroyed until we call free_lock()
        UseResource();
        lock->free_lock();
    }
    // else rundown is begin
}
```

and when we want begin destoy resource, we call

```
Lock* lock;
lock->BeginRunDown();
```

note, that we can safe call `BeginRunDown();` any count of time.

the `BeginRunDown();` not direct call `OnRundown()` ( where we can begin self destroy resource ) but mark resource as, not start use it more

if no other threads at time inside `take_lock()/free_lock()` block - `OnRundown()` will be directly called on current thread. otherwise this call will be on another thread, which is the last call `free_locl();`

after call `BeginRunDown();` another threads can continue safe use resourse, but new calls to `take_lock()` return false.

after last thread call `free_lock()` (after `BeginRunDown();` called ), the `OnRundown()` will be called on this thread. here we can start destroy resource (or send signal to another thread to do this )

also nothe that instead `-1` the `INT_MIN` is used as start value and compare not to `-1` but with `< 0`

Answer (score -1):

When using atomic there is an option to do "lock free programing". This may look easy, but has lots of subtle traps. For example it is bad idea to use `int8_t` with `std::atomic` it since it can be slower for multiple reasons (`int8_t` is sow by itself and also this greatly increases danger of "false sharing").

In your case this may look like this:

```cpp
struct Lock
{
    void take_lock()
    {
        auto original = m_counter.load();
        int newValue;
        do {
            while(original == -1) {
                m_counter.wait(original);
                original = m_counter.load();
            }
            newValue = original + 1;
        } while (!m_counter.compare_exchange_strong(original, newValue));
    }

    std::atomic<int> m_counter{0};
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rTYWdWr6h

For more details see cppcon talk from Herb Sutter ["Lock-Free Programming (or, Juggling Razor Blades)"](https://youtu.be/c1gO9aB9nbs) (note that title indicates that mastery is required) ([Part II](https://youtu.be/CmxkPChOcvw)).

**Disclaimer**: this answer is just a hint where to look for information how to address this problem not recommendation of final production code. As I mention at the beginning "this may look easy", but it is not.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, in part because you have typos and `auto original =` attempts to call the copy constructor of `m_counter`. You probably meant `= m_counter.load()`. Also, using `compare_exchange_strong` in a loop is pointless. If you have to spin, use `compare_exchange_weak`. I also don't really get the idea with the nested loop. Busy-waiting on atomics is also bad; use `std::atomic::wait()`.

Comment: @JanSchultke fixed the compilation issues (I should do the check before posting answer). Didn't use at first `std::atomic::wait` since it is C++20 feature, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: `original = m_counter.load()` can be `m_counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`.  The OP's requested `acq_rel` ordering can go on the atomic RMW, the CAS.  Also, why CAS_strong?  It's in a retry loop anyway, and on spurious failure (of the store-conditional on an LL/SC machine) there's little benefit to trying again without redoing the `== -1` and `+1`.